# saving to database takes too long

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

In my application I create an userControl, and then I need to save it to the database. Here is my method, where I'm saving my userControl :

```
private void SaveControl(byte userControlType, ISelectableViewModel viewModel, Guid guid)
{
    var context = new EntitiesNew();

    var instrumentSettings = new INSTRUMENTSETTINGS
                               {
                                   USERCONTROL = userControlType,
                                   INSTRUMENTHEIGHT = (float)viewModel.InstrumentHeight,
                                   INSTRUMENTWIDTH = (float)viewModel.InstrumentWidth,
                                   INSTRUMENTSCALABLEVALUE = viewModel.ScalableValue,
                                   INSTRUMENTPOSTOLEFT = (float)viewModel.InstrumentPosToLeft,
                                   INSTRUMENTPOSTOTOP = (float)viewModel.InstrumentPosToTop,
                                   INSTRUMENTZINDEX = viewModel.ZIndex,
                                   CREATED_BY= guid
                               };

    context.INSTRUMENTSETTINGSs.Add(instrumentSettings);
    context.SaveChanges();

    viewModel.ControlId = instrumentSettings.INSTRUMENTSETTINGSID;

    var roomId = (from room in context.ROOMs 
                 where room.ROOMNAME == viewModel.RoomName
                 select room.ROOMID).FirstOrDefault();

    var roomWithInstrument = new ROOMWITHINSTRUMENT
                         {
                             CREATED_BY = guid,
                             INSTRUMENTSETTINGSID = viewModel.ControlId,
                             ROOMID = roomId
                         };

    context.ROOMWITHINSTRUMENTs.Add(roomWithInstrument);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

There are no errors, and it's working. The only problem is, that when I'm saving for the first time record to database, it's taking too long (like 2 seconds). After first saving it's working better(less then a second). So my question is - how can I improve first saving, so it will be saving faster?

Comment: are you connecting to the database each time or once? What database provider are you using?

Comment: Obviously not the best suggestion,   while app is loading, write some insignificant change to the Database :)

Comment: Does the first query of the database take 2 seconds as well?

Comment: Is this in a release build, or are you running in debug mode from visual studio? When run from debug mode in VS it takes a bit longer because it is loading debugging symbols.

Comment: @iabbott: each time when I need to save userControl, I connect to database. We are using SQL database server

Comment: @TomerW: I don't understand your suggestion. What should it show to me?

Comment: @Sasha if your database is on a server then the delay on the first access is likely to be server side.. can you run exactly the same query a second time after to compare the time taken?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, it is in debug mode. Is it really taking so much longer, just because it's saving some debug symbols?

Comment: @iabbott you mean after the first save run this querry again?

Comment: Debug mode does a lot more than just saving debug symbols, it prevents MANY optimizations from happening that would make it much harder to debug (like instruction reordering). However I don't think that is your problem, I think you are seeing the one time initialization costs of starting up Entity framework. (Also your `context` should be inside a using blocks)

Comment: @Sasha yes, or what Tomer W suggested, do a simple database select during the app startup and see if that helps the write time

Comment: @ScottChamberlain is there any way to avoid this costs or minimize?

Comment: @iabbott when the querry runs second time, it's way much faster. So as I understand, to some simple select during startup will help to solve this problem, but if there is another way to solve it, because in this case application will be loading longer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should be putting your context in a `using` block

```
private void SaveControl(byte userControlType, ISelectableViewModel viewModel, Guid guid)
{
    using(var context = new EntitiesNew())
    {
        var instrumentSettings = //...

        //...

         context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If you don't do that you are not releasing the connections back to the connection pool when you are done and it can cause performance issues for you as your program runs.

On to your actual problem: Entity Framework does a lot of extra "stuff" the first time per AppDomain it connects to a database. You are seeing it happen the first query you call, however you can make it happen sooner.

```
public static void InitializeDatabaseConnection()
{
    using(var context = new EntitiesNew())
    {
        context.Database.Initialize(false);
    }
}
```

That method will initialize the connection for the current AppDomain and allow the first query to be faster. I would just run this method inside a task at the start of your program.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Assumes you put the function inside the EntitiesNew class
    Task.Run(() => EntitiesNew.InitializeDatabaseConnection()); 

    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```